# Coin Toss - Game is finished when someone reaches their goal of winning

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Person A and Person B toss a fair coin.
Person A wins a single toss when the coin falls on heads, and person B wins a single toss when the coin falls on tails.
The goal of A is to win twice (total in the game), and the goal of B is to win 3 times.
The grand winner is the person who reaches their goal first.

1. What is the probability that A wins? (P(A))?

I already calculated this one by drawing a probability tree and reaching the answer of $11/16$
 [the tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elDMI.png)

2. What is the estimated value in the game, E(X)?

I'm not sure if I should do an average in the tree of the max tosses of 4 or not, please help

3. Lets mark with P(n,m) the probability that A wins the game when his goal is n and B's goal is m. Using  ${\displaystyle \ P(B)=\sum _{i}P(B|A_{i})P(A_{i})}{\displaystyle \ P(B)=\sum _{i}P(B|A_{i})P(A_{i})}$, find $\ F_{{n+1}}=F_{n}+F_{{n-1}}$ for $P(n,m)$.

I could use a direction on how to start.

Comment: What is $F$ supposed to mean in part 3?

Comment: F is the sequence example to find the sequence for P(n,m). English is not my first language so I ment Recurrence Equation

Answer (score 1):

To get the expected value you need to define the payoff.  If $A$ wins $1$ on winning and loses $1$ on losing his expected value is $\frac {11}{16}(+1)+\frac 5{16}(-1)=\frac 6{16}$